# Not getting member center option

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

My client enrolled for apple developer program & assigned me Admin roles I got an invitation from apple which I accepted and I successfully logged-in to itunesconnect but when am going into apple.developer.com to create certificates & all that am not able to see that Member Center option.

Instead, am seeing this page.

[image]